# Add new UITableViewController to existing storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uitableview

I have created a small universal app with the Master-Detail template. Everything worked fine, I was able to see an alphabetized list of employees either on the iPhone or in a split view on an iPad (I have two storyboards).

But now I want to insert a UITableViewController in front of the Master View Controller so I can list viewing options like "Employee by Name," "Employees by City", etc.

How can I insert a new UITableViewController and make it the initial view controller?

Answer (score 1):

drag a icon like this: [image] onto the storyboard. Then drag the arrow pointing right (which is currently attached to your master controller) onto the new controller. The new controller will become the initial one.